# why is typedef used with enum type?

Tags: objective-c, c, enums, typedef

why is typedef needed in the code below?

```
typedef enum _Coordinate {
    CoordinateX = 0,    ///< X axis
    CoordinateY = 1,    ///< Y axis
    CPCoordinateZ = 2   ///< Z axis
} Coordinate;
```

why not just have the code below and remove the typedef?

```
enum Coordinate {
    CoordinateX = 0,    ///< X axis
    CoordinateY = 1,    ///< Y axis
    CPCoordinateZ = 2   ///< Z axis
};
```

Comment: names starting with an underscore followed by an upper case letter are reserved in any context (it's what new C keywords use: eg `_Bool`, `_Complex` from C99, `_Atomic`, `_Generic` from C1x) - use a trailing underscore instead...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't `typedef` your enum, in your other code you have to refer to it as `enum Coordinate` instead of just `Coordinate`, even though you *know* `Coordinate` is an enum. It's just to eliminate the redundancy of the `enum` keyword when referring to it, I guess.

To make it clearer, here's what it would look like if you `typedef` it separately from declaring it:

```
enum _Coordinate {
    CoordinateX = 0,
    CoordinateY = 1,
    CPCoordinateZ = 2
};

// You map the enum type "enum _Coordinate" to a user-defined type "Coordinate"
typedef enum _Coordinate Coordinate;
```

This also applies to C structs and enums (Obj-C enums are just C enums anyway).